# Vector field not displaying correctly with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a vector field with matplotlib, however it doesn't plot correctly and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The vector field to be plotted is the magnetic field of an infinitely long straight wire at a fixed height. What I should get is this:

[image]

I know that the equation for the vector field (in cylindrical coordinates) is:

B(r) = (u0/2*pi)*(i/r)

where:
u0 is a constant (positive),
i is the current in the wire,
r is the distance from the wire (the z axis).

Here is the picture I get by using the code below:
[image]
As you can see, aside from the problem with the center of the wire, the vectors in the left half are directed in the wrong direction.
Also, is there a function to plot the field in 3d? such as quiver3 in matlab?
Thanks

```
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

def E(x,y):
    i = 3
    mu = 2
    mag = (mu/(2*np.pi))*(i/np.sqrt((x)**2+(y)**2))
    ey = mag * (np.cos(np.arctan(y/x)))
    ex = mag * (-np.sin(np.arctan(y/x)))
    return ex,ey

ex,ey = E(x,y)
plt.quiver(x,y,ex,ey,pivot='middle',color='r',headwidth=4,headlength=6)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Inverse trigonometric functions are [only defined on specific intervals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTrigonometricFunctions.html).  The arrows pointing the wrong way is not a plotting error, but an oversight in calculating `ex, ey`.  **Spoiler: you want to use `np.arctan2`**.

Comment: What a silly mistake I made! thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The long arrows at the core are due to the magnetic field blowing up very close to the wire.  Either remove/mask x,y values in your grid which correspond to `r=sqrt(x**2 + y**2) < r_min` for some `r_min` such that those big arrows are removed, or increase the spacing of your mesh grid so those big arrows have some room to breathe.
2. The wrong arrow directions for `x<0` are due to you using `arctan` instead of `arctan2` which is [specifically designed for use in 4 quadrants](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) (measured from the +x axis).
3. There is indeed a [3D quiver](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#quiver). To get started with that, you can do

---

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, Y, Z = #3D meshgrid of positions
U, V, W = #3D meshgrid of directions

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, U, V, W, **kwargs)
```